# EJB method returns a different HashMap?

Tags: java, jpa, hashmap

I'm developing an application where people insert and manage trips with participants. I'm using JPA and have a Trip entity that contains a list of Participations entities. Now, I don't have the name mapped on the Participations table on the DB, but there is a Employee entity that does it, and the Participation entity contains the Employee ID.

I wrote an EJB TripBean implementation that has a method that gets a Trip as parameter and returns a Map containing pairs of  with the Employee IDs and their names:

```
public Map<Integer, String> getEmployeeNames(Trip trip) {
    Map<Integer, String> employeeNames = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for (Participation participation : trip
            .getParticipations()) {
        Employee employee = jpaBean
                .getEmployeeByID(participation.getEmployeeId());
        employeeNames.put(new Integer(employee.getEmployeeId()
                .intValue()),
                employee.getName());
    }
    return employeeNames;
}
```

Now, in the Manager method i use this hashmap to set the transient field String employeeName in Participation (this is in another class, not in the same EJB):

```
Map<Integer, String> employeeNames = tripBean
            .getEmployeeNames(trip);
for (Participation participation : trip.getParticipations()) {
    String employeeName = employeeNames.get(participation.getEmployeeId());
    participation.setEmployeeName(employeeName);
}
```

My problem is, when I get the map back from tripBean.getEmployeeNames() it is different from the one I see when I'm in the getEmployeeNames method: it contains less entries, and they don't correspond to the ones I saw the method put together.
I'm sure I'm screwing up with some best practice, can anyone help?

Additional info:
- I debugged the error on my local machine as the only user logged, so I think it does not depend on other users accessing the same classes concurrently.
- I have Trips and Participations defined on a different persistence context than Employees. I thus can't create a JPA relationship between them, or set the employeeName field in Participation in a postConstruct method

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out where the problem was: employeeId in Participation is of type BigDecimal and not Integer, and thus the get() method didn't find anything. This solved the problem:

```
String employeeName = employeeNames.get(participation.getEmployeeId().intValue());
```

I still don't know why in debug I see a different hashmap than what I put together in my EJB method, but at this point I guess it's just the debugger rendering the data differently :/